# How do I convert a scrolling view into a ListView in Flutter?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, user-experience

I have a scrolling view of a few cards in a stack. Upon scrolling the card selected disappears. I want to retain this card and the consequent card and have all of them displayed in a ListView and not disappear. 
I saw this feature implemented in this repository and it looks like this:

[image]
However this shows me only one card at a time. I want to achieve the cards to transition into a list view after removed from the stack. 
So I tried implementing this and it worked but I wasn't able to achieve the stack below. 
This is the code for my implementation:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final _pageController = PageController(
    viewportFraction: 0.3,
  );

  List<CreditCard> _creditCards = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _creditCards = [
      CreditCard(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
        ),
        image: 'images/visa.png',
        name: 'ANDREW MITCHELL',
        number: '1234',
        company: Text(
          'AMERICAN \nEXPRESS',
          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
            fontSize: 16,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      CreditCard(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: kRed.withOpacity(0.4),
        ),
        image: 'images/visa.png',
        name: 'ANDREW MITCHELL',
        number: '2434',
        company: Image.asset(
          'images/virgin.png',
          height: 50,
        ),
      ),
      CreditCard(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
            end: Alignment.centerRight,
            colors: [kBlue, kPurple],
            stops: [0.3, 0.95],
          ),
        ),
        image: 'images/mastercard.png',
        name: 'ANDREW MITCHELL',
        number: '4567',
        company: Text(
          'AMERICAN \nEXPRESS',
          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
            fontSize: 16,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: PageView.builder(
          controller: _pageController,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemCount: _creditCards.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => _builder(index),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _builder(int index) {
    CreditCard _card = _creditCards[index];
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _pageController,
      builder: (context, child) {
        double value = 1.6;

        if (_pageController.position.haveDimensions) {
          value = _pageController.page - index;

          if (value >= 0) {
            double _lowerLimit = 0+1.55;
            double _upperLimit = pi / 2;

            value = (_upperLimit - (value.abs() * (_upperLimit - _lowerLimit)))
                .clamp(_lowerLimit, _upperLimit);
            value = _upperLimit - value;
            value *= -1;
          }
        } else {
          if (index == 0) {
            value = 0;
          } else if (index == 1) {
            value = -1;
          }
        }

        return Center(
          child: Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.identity()
              ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
              ..rotateX(value),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: child,
          ),
        );
      },
      child: _card,
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Your listView must be of a certain size Otherwise it spreads to fullscreen.You can put it on a Container of specified height or use Expanded widget.

Comment: Full screen is fine I just want to add the card stack part below my list view. Can you suggest a way to do that ?
I wanted to implement the stack as in this repo https://github.com/ossgoossgo/flutter-practice/blob/582c563b409bb2f2bfd450649b61afe640b70bb9/lib/credit_cards.dart